# SMIL animations fail on dynamically loaded external SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, dom-events, smil

I've created a monster animated SVG file with over 3000 paths. Each path animates independently using declarative SMIL animations. It plays slowly but beautifully in all new browsers, using a little js fallback for IE9. (I'd post a link but it wouldn't clarify anything.)

I developed the page using HTML5 and inline SVG. Just as I was finishing, I realized that I didn't want to force mobile browsers to choke on this huge file. So I moved the svg to an external file, and added all the xml declarations back in. I'm calling the external svg after the important info in the page has already rendered, using some conditional logic and some textbook ajax:

```
function loadThatSvg(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('get','floral.svg',true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status === 304 ) {
                var flowers = xhr.responseXML.getElementById('floralpaths');
                var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
                stage.appendChild(flowers);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(loadThatSvg,3000);
}
```

Inspector tools in the various browsers show the file is getting loaded correctly. The problem is that the animations are never triggered, so nothing happens! They're there in the DOM. I can see them. But whatever timer or event that kicks off SMIL animations *in markup* doesn't appear to apply to *dynamically loaded* animation elements.

But then I read [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628888) on Bugzilla, which focuses on this use case, and suggests that the problem has been solved (though for my tests in FF13 it clearly hasn't). Hmm...

Is there some custom function or declaration I can use to start the clock on SMIL animations in dynamically loaded SVG content? Even if the answer is flat-out "no," it would be nice for folks like me to know one way or the other. Thanks for any clarification!

UPDATE:

Here's the raw svg file. It works in FF, Opera, and Webkit. Be patient please:

[http://bit . ly/LC3LEQ](http://socializepalmsprings.com/archivereference/floral-b.svg)

And here's a page that references that very same SVG file, from the same domain. I've changed the `appendChild` statement in my earlier code to include an `adoptNode()` method, which gets it working in FF13 and Opera 11.64, but the animation is still never kicked off in webkit:

[http://bit . ly/Mk0lnz](http://socializepalmsprings.com/archivereference/full23adoptedroot.html)

Comment: Are you sure the loaded svg is in the right namespace? You should probably use stage.appendChild(document.importNode(flowers, true)) too. If you're still stuck then providing a complete example online would be useful.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm sure you're right but can you explain why to use importNode()? Also, if I do go this route, can you possibly elucidate the difference between importNode() and adoptNode()? What's the difference between "copying" and "moving" the nodes? Docs are unclear on this. It seems like adoptNode would be more appropriate in this case, since I want the whole SVG subtree (assuming of course that browser support is there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a host of bugs in Webkit happening here:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82647

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74801

The only way that I was able to get the animations going in Webkit was to iterate over them, get the target values from the svg markup, and animate them manually with jquery animate(). None of the svg specific methods worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways you can do this. Note that I've assumed that you've already inserted the animated document into the main document.

First way, by starting the animations with script:

- get each animation element that you want to trigger and then call [beginElement()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl) on it

The second way is to reset the current time in the document, which the animation elements are relative to. This might work, you'll have to test and see:

- get the root svg element of the animated document, and call [setCurrentTime(0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__setCurrentTime) on it

If you go for the second one, and it doesn't work, you can also try pausing and unpausing, like this:

- get the root svg element of the animated document (variable 'svgroot' below)
- call svgroot.[pauseAnimations()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations)
- call svgroot.[setCurrentTime(0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__setCurrentTime)
- call svgroot.[unpauseAnimations()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__unpauseAnimations)

Comment: Thanks Erik. Please see update above. Your first method (iterating over all the paths) doesn't work for me. Here's a link: http://bit.ly/KQjcuU Two issues: First, FF throws the error that setting beginElementAt() on a 'set' element is illegal. Still, the animation works anyways with the adoptNode() method, as before in FF, so no harm done. Chrome however crashes utterly on this page. I'm slightly helpless trying to debug without the console in Chrome! Also, do beginElement() and beginElementAt() work on 'set' elements or just 'animate' elements? The spec/docs are unclear.

Comment: I need the 'set' elements to be retimed along with the animate elements, because the 'set' elements are there to work around a known bug in Chrome with 'fill="freeze"' not working correctly in animate elements. (This has been fixed in Canary builds of Chrome but I need it for now.) Also, some docs say that beginElement() only works on animate elements that have a markup value of begin="indefinite" which is obviously not the case here. Lastly I tried both versions of your second method (resetting the timer) as well. See second link in the update. Neither method get things going in Webkit.

Comment: using setCurrentTime works in current versions of Chrome (32), but not in Safari.