# SVG SMIL animation bug in Safari

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been looking at an article about SVG animations.

```
Code: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/DpFfE
```

Article: http://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/

Works good except for in Safari desktop (and I guess also on iOS).
The button should toggle between a yellow star and a green check symbol.

The animations work good the first two times the animation runs and the third time I get a green star instead of a green check. So the color animation did run but not the shape animation. After that it's all wrong.

Any ideas on whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Report it as a webkit bug to the webkit bug tracker.

Comment: done. but in the meantime, any ideas on how to do this in another way and get it working in safari? preferably without any large library like snap.svg

Comment: I had minor success with this methodology:
call svgroot.pauseAnimations()
call svgroot.setCurrentTime(0)
call svgroot.unpauseAnimations()
recommended in this thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942013/smil-animations-fail-on-dynamically-loaded-external-svg

Slightly updated codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raZGVW

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I solved with help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945392/2594391): 
the trick is restart the timing for the animation with shape your svg inits:

```
var variconMorphID = document.getElementById("navbar-icon-hot");

var animationToHome = document.getElementById("morph-to-home");
var animationToFire = document.getElementById("morph-to-fire");

if (button.classList.contains("saved")) {
    button.classList.remove("saved");
    animationToFire.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    button.classList.add("saved");

    variconMorphID.pauseAnimations();
    variconMorphID.setCurrentTime(0);
    variconMorphID.unpauseAnimations();

    animationToHome.beginElement();
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Saved!";
  }
```

Here is an example in CODEPEN:

http://codepen.io/jesuscmd/details/wWBEgR/